# What is the point of basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Why do we even bother with basis vectors? Why don't we just notate an element $x$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ as an ordered set $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and go from there?

Comment: Because as you'll probably soon see, it is very useful to be able to change basis depending on the linear map we are talking about.

Comment: Simon S has given the most important point for finite dimensional linear algebra. Another important point is simply that we need bases for *many* applications in infinite dimensions, which justifies discussing them in the easier setting of finite dimensions.

Comment: Yes you will see why they are also useful when you begin the topic of coordinates

Comment: an ordered set $(x_1.....x_n), x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ represents different vectors in different basis.

Comment: Suppose I give you an arbitrary plane in 3D Euclidean space passing through the origin. It is a 2-dimensional vector space. How would you denote a point on it as $(x_1,x_2)$? See also this MathOverflow question: [Vector spaces without natural bases](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32397/vector-spaces-without-natural-bases).

Comment: Writing an element as an ordered set $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ is exactly the same thing as choosing a basis.